# launchOptions and persistent Wifi connection

Tags: ios, wifi, cllocation

I am working on `iOS` app that uses `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` to know if users have arrived at destination. When he arrives, the app is started with `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and `launchOptions`, then starts to call the server and keeps refreshing.

After a few seconds, the app can not call the website anymore because all data connections are stopped unless I press the power button.

Can any one help me? Thank you

Comment: Sounds like the app is going into suspend mode. I don't think you can make network connections when the phone is in sleep mode.

Comment: Thank you. I am using background location updates and background fresh capability. I am using [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES and UIRequiresPersistentWiFi in plist, but both are not working. The app worked before iOS 7